# AJAX no Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Estou tentando fazer mandar dados para meu controller usando AJAX porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> AJAX error: error : Not Found

Oque posso estar fazendo para resolver este problema?

segue os códigos:

route:

```
Route::post('/update/{postdata}', 'ReportsController@updateReport');
```

controller:

```
    public function updateReport()
{   

    dd('Chegou no controller');

    }
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
                          function mudar(obj){
                          var selecionado = obj.checked;
                          if (selecionado) {
                            var id = '1';
                            $.ajax({
                            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
                            url: '/update', // This is the url we gave in the route
                            data: {"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}", 'id' : id}, // a JSON object to send back
                            success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                                console.log(response); 
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                            }
                            });
                            alert('fechado');
                          } else {
                            alert('aberto');
                          }
                          }
                      </script>
```

Comment: A rota precisa de um parâmetro `/update/{postdata}` no seu ajax vc ta mandando apenas `update`.

Answer (score -1):

Olá uma forma que você pode fazer isso é utilizando o axios que é um cliente http criado em js. mas se eu apenas falar isso ficará muito vago então vou fazer um exemplo bem simples.

passo 1: criamos uma model e sua respectiva migration

```
php artisan make:model Report -m
```

passo 2: colocar alguns dados em sua migration

```
//não esqueça de importar sua model se for inserir aqui, sem criar seeders
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Report::create([
            'name' => 'Jão das Goiabas',
            'description' => 'João planta goiabas vermelhas que são saborosas',
        ]);
        Report::create([
            'name' => 'Zézinho das mangas',
            'description' => 'Zezinho compra manga para sua família',
        ]);


    }
```

passo 3: Rodar a migration.

```
php artisan migrate
```

passo 4: vamos criar nossas rotas, eu coloquei os métodos de criação nas rotas, mas perceba que isso é um exemplo, faça isso em seu controller

```
use \App\Report;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $reports= Report::all();
    return view('crud')->with('reports', $reports);
});

//--CREATE a Reports--//
Route::post('/reports', function (Request $request) {
    $report= Report::create($request->all());
    return Response::json($reports);
});
```

Agora que já temos esses dados vamos para o js

passo 5: baixe o axios ou utilize algum cdn
[AXIOS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.js)

passo 6: arquivo para submit form, esse arquivo será crud.blade.php

```
<heade>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<!-- outros imports pertinents -->
</heade>
<div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
        placeholder="Enter name" value="">

</div>

<div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description"
        placeholder="Enter Description" value="">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="saveData()" id="btn-save" value="add"></button>
</div>
<script src="{{url('seu_arquivo_axios')}}"></script>
```

passo 7: criação do js

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
saveData = function () {
    let selectReportName = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]')
    let reportName = selectReportName.value
    let selectDescription = document.querySelector('input[name="description"]')
    let description = selectDescription.value
    axios.post('/reports', {
            name: reportName,
            description: description
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status == '200') {
                window.location.href = "/"
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

isso deve funcionar.
Link de inspiração: [crud ajax laravel](https://github.com/AndreMart/laravel-crud-ajax)